# S104-Sonarqube- ¿is it possible that the "Summary" or comments are not added in the total amount per file?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

S104-Files with more than 1000 lines, Sonarqube counts the lines of comments and summary for the Total of lines per file, ¿is it possible that the "Summary" comments are not added in the total amount per file?, But only count the actual lines of code?.

We know that we can extend the size of 1000 lines in case it is extremely necessary, however according to the rule to leave files less complex and more maintainable, we do not want to increase the standard limit, but adjust to the 1000 lines of code per file.

I'm using: SonarQube 5.6.6
Updated version of the latest plug in
[S104_Example_Count_Comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMRY3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've changed our philosophy on these "too many lines" rules this year. Instead of counting lines, all such implementations should be adjusted to count lines of code. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/396) for the C# implementation of this rule.